# Uncaught Error: Interface 'League\Flysystem\FilesystemAdapter' not found in magento2

Tags: magento2.4

when

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

display

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Interface 'League\Flysystem\FilesystemAdapter' not found in /home/magento2-dev/public_html/app/code/Magento/RemoteStorage/Driver/Adapter/CachedAdapterInterface.php:15
```

How to do

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at both your `app/code/` and `vendor/` directories, do you see any module named `Flysystem` under `League` vendor name?

In case you do - module `League_Flysystem` does exist in your project, maybe try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691994/calling-flysystem-why-do-i-get-php-fatal-error-class-league-flysystem-adapter).

Otherwise, you might need to pull the particular module to your project, preferably using **Composer**:

```
composer require league/flysystem
```

Then check your `vendor/` directory and execute command DI compile command again.

Happy coding!